# Provide Proxy Information to Job

Tags: concourse

Wondering if anyone has come across this: Is it possible to provide proxy information to Concourse job? Something along lines of this:

```
- name: bosh-deploy-0
  ...
  jobs:
  - name: deploybosh
    properties:
      http_proxy_url: <http_proxy_url>:<http_proxy_port>
      https_proxy_url: <https_proxy_url>:<http_proxy_port>
      no_proxy:
      - localhost
      - 127.0.0.1
```

If anyone has a working example, I'd be very much appreaciative!!

Answer (score 1):

You can only set these properties per worker. https://github.com/concourse/concourse-bosh-release/blob/v4.2.1/jobs/worker/spec#L142-L153.

If you want a job to run with specific proxy information set, you need to

1. Deploy a worker with those properties set, and with some [worker tag](https://github.com/concourse/concourse-bosh-release/blob/v4.2.1/jobs/worker/spec#L137-L140).
2. Configure every step of the job with that same [tag](https://concourse-ci.org/tags-step-modifier.html#tags).

Answer (score 0):

You could also set the proxy settings at the beginning of your job task (and optionally pass the proxy endpoint with parameters or a config server backend). That's maybe not the nicest way, however, it works quite well.